# Wordpress Homepage showing error rather than displaying the homepage

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress website homepage showing

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

And when You Reload The page it is working...Why is this Happening?

ps: I didn't use any cache plugin

Comment: you didn't give us enough info... what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: when you are opening your Wordpress website homepage the above three lines of code is displayed and when you hit  Reload button of your browser it is displaying the homepage

Comment: in which file are those lines?

Comment: Looks like it's possibly content of your robots.txt file, try deleting it (after making a copy) and see what happens

Comment: @DaFois i dont know the file destination.

Comment: @aMJay ok I will try.

Comment: @aMJay I am unable to find robots.txt file?

Comment: did you install yoast seo plugin ?

Comment: what will happen when you install seo plugin ?

Comment: Yes , YOAST SEO plugin is installed.